# What is the meaning of DSQUOTA and NSQUOTA columns in Hadoop FsImage?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, namenode

I have taken a dump of fsimage using [OIV](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html) tool and NSQUOTA and DSQUOTA fields always have one of the following values

NSQUOTA

- 1
- null
- -1
- 0

DSQUOTA

- -1
- 0

What does NSQUOTA and DSQUOTA represent? How to interpret these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSQUOTA is a name quota (similar to inodes) which limits how many files and directories are allowed under the specified directory.

DSQUOTA is a directory space quota which limits how many bytes are allowed under that directory.

Not sure about the other values but the `-1` is the default value when you don't use quotas.

#### References

- [HDFS Quotas Guide - v2.8.0](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsQuotaAdminGuide.html)

Comment: For DSQUOTA the document says "A quota of zero still permits files to be created, but no blocks can be added to the files." any idea why a file can be created but no blocks can be added?

Comment: I suppose you could use this if you wanted to allow a directory structure to be created.  I think when Yahoo! designed this, they incorporated a lot of ideas from a shared UNIX/Linux environments running NFS which would be common 2007-2009.  This same line is there in the earliest docs.  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.11/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsQuotaAdminGuide.html